# Missing partition space after running diskutil commands

Tags: macos, partition, storage

I was trying to merge 2 partitions into 1 on my MacBook Pro 2012 running macOS Sierra 10.12.6. At first, with the command

> diskutil list

I got this

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
       #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
       0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *240.1 GB   disk0
       1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
       2:                  Apple_HFS MAC 2                   107.8 GB   disk0s2
       3:                  Apple_HFS MAC                     131.3 GB   disk0s3
       4:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s4
```

But after I used this command to delete Mac 2 (disk0s2):

> diskutil erasevolume "Free Space" "" /dev/disk0s2

I got this:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *240.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS MAC                     131.3 GB   disk0s3
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s4
```

And the free space of Mac 2 is completely lost, I can't find it in Disk utility anymore.

Can someone please tell me how to fix this?